# .Netcore WebApi return user error to a vue app to be displayed to user...may have coded myself into a corner looking for a better answer

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on a .NetCore 3.1 webApi talking to a Vue app.

In MVC c# .Net we had a generic way to handle validation and user errors that worked nicely.

We'd throw a RulesException, and the Controller code would handle passing it to the MVC Client, which handled popping it up and displaying it's messages to the user. Worked really nicely and simply, even elegantly when we setup generic exception handlers and didn't have to rewrite the code for each call....

I'm trying to set up something similar in the new .NetCore API to return user errors to a Vue app.

For now we added a base class for all DataObjects returned through the API, BaseDataObject which has 2 fields, errorMsg and errorType *(severity level).

```
 public class BaseDataObject
    {
        string errorType;
        public string ErrorType
...
```

All classes returned by the API must derive from this object.

The idea being that we return those fields to with data via json to the vue app and it knows to display that to the user, and the WebApi can make the Json automatically.
(1 error at a time only, obviously.)

Problem 1, Some methods return an object of a class derived from BaseDataObject, others return a list of them. This makes the vue code have to look for the JOSN wrapped in a list, or not depending on the return type of teh API call, which is sloppy.

I could fix this by changing it to wrap all lists in an object which itself derives from BaseDataObject, instead of the objects in the list deriving from it,  but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution without the overhead.

Problem 2, how to generically handle the situation for all exceptions of said type... Preferably in one place, for all API calls.

Doing it manually for each method would look something like this:(StudentAdDataResponse is derived from BaseDataObject)

```
    catch ( ApiErrorException ex )
    {
        log.LogError( ex.ToString() );

        var errorObjectList = new List<StudentAdDataResponse>();
        errorObjectList.Add( new StudentAdDataResponse() { ErrorMsg = ex.Message, ErrorType = ex.Type }  );

        return errorObjectList;
    }
```

Problem 3: My first approach to improving the fully manual code above was to try to write a Generic to handle that, but it'd need to be a generic for only types derived from BaseDataObejct, which has me stumped. which puts me back to mistake prone manual code for every method(ick).

I'd love to handle all Exceptions of ApiErrorExceptions in one place, and then generically return Json to the Vue code to handle the problem. But I seem to be on the wrong tack and coded myself into a bit of a corner.

Whatever answer needs to work for validation errors, and for throwing manually in the c# code, as we have plenty of both..

I feel like this problem -must- have been faced and handled before in other projects, I'd love to hear any elegant solutions y'all can suggest.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 5 I would streamline the Exception Handling by adding following code to the Middleware pipeline:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(appException =>
        {
            appException.Run(async context =>
            {
                var exceptionFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                if(exceptionFeature.Error is ApiErrorException exception)
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new BaseDataObject 
                    { 
                        errorType = exception.GetType().ToString(),
                        errorMessage = exception.Message
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Where can I find context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync? ( tried googling for nutget packages but was unsuccessful, thanks.

Comment: Our app is .NetCore 3.1, i tried rewriting it using newton soft to generate the JSON, but it's not getting called when an Exception is thrown.

Comment: WriteAsJsonAsync is only available from .NET 5 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Davids soloution compiled, once i rewrote it to use NewtonSoft to generqate the JSON, but never go called.

This however did work in .netCore 3.1 webApi

add->new class->

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using StudentPortal4Api.Dto;

namespace StudentPortal4Api.Utilities
{

    public class ApiErrorExceptionFilter : IActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
    {
        public int Order { get; } = int.MaxValue - 10;

        public void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext context ) { }

        public void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext context )
        {
            if ( context.Exception is ApiErrorException exception )
            {
                var bdo = new BaseDataObject(exception.Message, exception.Type);

                context.Result           = new JsonResult( bdo ) { };
                context.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this to startup.cs ConfigureServices

```
services.AddControllers( options => options.Filters.Add( new ApiErrorExceptionFilter() ) );
```